# is it possible in php loop without nested loop

Tags: php, integer

I want to print like this using loop without nested loop:

```
1
2   3
4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
```

- first line start from 1 and print only one integer
- second line start from 2 and print two integer
- third line start from 4 and print four integer
- fourth line start from 8 and print eight integer
- (same condition in other line if exist)

Comment: What's your initial datas ?

Comment: Can you please post your current nested loop code?

Comment: for($i=1; $i <= 15; $i++)

Comment: Without more context `echo "1\n2   3\n4   5   6   7\n8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15\n";` would fulfil your requirements.

Comment: its not dynamic idea.

Comment: you'll need recursion. and a way to exit your infinite loop. also, a starting point wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pair of counters should do the trick;

```
$threshold = 1;
$x = 1;
for($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    echo $i . ' ';

    if($x == $threshold) {
        echo "<br>\n";
        $threshold = $threshold * 2;
        $x = 0;
    }

    $x++;
}
```

Will keep on working till infinity, or your script runs out of memory. Whatever comes first :)

Comment: Looks like the good solution here :) I just put it in a ideone in order to show your solution. https://ideone.com/d2JJz1

Comment: may be there is a tab not a space

Comment: I was implementing solution with log($i,2) but this seems a lot simpler and easier to work with.

Comment: @kaldoran ideone seems like a pretty cool tool. Wish I'd known of it before :)

Comment: ok.. its work. 
can you explain this code please..

Comment: Certainly. Basically, as we loop over the numbers you want to display ($i), we also increment a second variable ($x). When $x becomes equal to $threshold, we multiply $threshold by 2, and reset $x back to 0. At the sime time, we push out the line break.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve with single while and some array functions. Try this.

```
<?php
$start=1;
while($start<=10){
    $array = range($start,($start+$start-1));
    echo implode(' ',$array)."<br>";
    $start=$start*2;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$i=1;
$t=1;
while($i<1000)
{
    if($i==$t)
    {
        if($t!=1) echo "<br />";
        $t=$t*2;
    }
    echo $i." ";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it without any `for` and some recursion ;-)

```
<?php

$elements = range(1,15);

display($elements);

function display(array $parts, $step = 1) {
    if(! count($parts)) {
        return;
    }

    $elements = array_splice($parts, 0, $step);
    echo implode("\t", $elements)."\n";
    display($parts, $step * 2);
}
```

See the working code on https://eval.in/755277

Comment: this could lead to a huge stack, becouse the function calles itself and so the Memory used for every function-call has to be preserved until it finishes

Comment: I don't think this is more expansive for memory than others solutions. Can you prove it ?

Comment: According to https://3v4l.org/ukabB/perf#output and https://3v4l.org/SBVBB/perf#output , memory consumption seems equals.

Answer (score 0):

same thing but with log($i,2).

```
<?php

$i=1;

while($i<20)
{
        echo $i;
        $i++;
        if(filter_var(log($i,2), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
                echo PHP_EOL;
        else
                echo "\t";
}
```